# Conditional order by in linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

I have ViewModel as follows

```
public class LMS_ClassDiscussionListViewModel
{
    public  int ReplyCount { get; set; }
    public LMS_ClassDiscussion ClassDiscussion { get; set; }
}
```

and the model LMS_ClassDiscussion which is referred in above view model is as follows

```
public partial class LMS_ClassDiscussion
{
    [Key]
    public int ClassDiscussionID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentClassDiscussionID { get; set; }
    public int MessageTypeID { get; set; }
    public int ClassID { get; set; }
    public int DiscussionUserID { get; set; }
    public int NotificationStatusID { get; set; }
    public string Discussion { get; set; }
    public DateTime DiscussionDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrivate { get; set; }
    public bool IsRead { get; set; }
    public string DiscussionTitle { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the records in list as follows

```
List<LMS_ClassDiscussionListViewModel> modelList = GetData();
```

So, this list I want to sort based on `NotificationStatusID = 2`.

Means, those records which has `NotificationStatusID` as 2 it should come first and rest after that.

So, for this I have tried in below way but the list is not getting sorted

```
modelList = modelList.OrderBy(x => x.ClassDiscussion.NotificationStatusID)
                     .ThenBy(x => x.ClassDiscussion.NotificationStatusID == 2)
                     .ToList();
```

How can i sort this list with `NotificationStatusID = 2` ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can use concat (list of items having id =2 union items having id <>2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may first select your elements with Id = 2 and then concatenate the rest at the end using [`Enumerable.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = modelList.Where(x => x.ClassDiscussion.NotificationStatusID == 2)
        .Concat(modeList.Where(x => x.ClassDiscussion.NotificationStatusID != 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is to sort by `NotificationStatusID` as the main sort criterion, which will put everything in order. Then **within that order**, you order by `NotificationStatusID == 2`.

What you can do is to write a comparer that implements `IComparer<int>` and that puts all elements with a value of 2 on top of the list. Then you can use this comparer in `SortBy` (there is an overload for that).

If you want to save yourself the comparer, try this:

```
modelList = modelList.OrderBy(x => x.ClassDiscussion.NotificationStatusID == 2 ? Int32.MinValue : x.ClassDiscussion.NotificationStatusID)
```

That will treat all elements with a value of 2 as Int32.MinValue, which will move them right on top.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have no negatives, you can just do an `.OrderBy(m => m.ClassDiscussion.NotificationStatusID == 2 ? -1 :  m.ClassDiscussion.NotificationStatusID)`. This way you only have to traverse the list once.

Comment: Thanks for the help !